# Create a save function for multiple values

Tags: angularjs

I've created a table called `trailers`. This table has two columns, a `movie_id` and a `link` column.

I've created a JSONP function to get the data I want to save into the table,

```
service.trailer = function(youtube_link){
  return httpPromise(
    baseUrl + youtube_link + '/videos?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8**8d7cadad4&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
  )
};
```

This is the JSONP output from the request,

```
{"id":157336,"results":[
  {"id":"53db3c790e0a26189a000d09","iso_639_1":"en","key":"ePbKGoIGAXY","name":"Trailer 3","site":"YouTube","size":1080,"type":"Trailer"},
  {"id":"550df44b9251413554004d43","iso_639_1":"en","key":"KlyknsTJk0w","name":"Own it today","site":"YouTube","size":720,"type":"Trailer"},
  {"id":"533ec6fcc3a3685448009ccc","iso_639_1":"en","key":"nyc6RJEEe0U","name":"Teaser","site":"YouTube","size":720,"type":"Trailer"},
  {"id":"5376ab510e0a26141c0005a8","iso_639_1":"en","key":"zSWdZVtXT7E","name":"Trailer","site":"YouTube","size":720,"type":"Trailer"},
  {"id":"545da247c3a3685362005187","iso_639_1":"en","key":"Lm8p5rlrSkY","name":"Trailer 2","site":"YouTube","size":1080,"type":"Trailer"}
]}
```

The above data is from the movie Interstellar and it has 5 objects. Now I want to take the `key` value from each object and save it in my `trailer` table with the corresponding movie_id, which in this example is `157336`. I am using a Ruby on Rails backend with a SQLite database.

I think I need to use `forEach` and loop through each result and use a create function to save the data in the table. Something like this,

```
movieAdd.trailer(movie.id)
  .then(function(response){
    $scope.youtubeTrailer = [];
    angular.forEach(response.results, function(item){
      if (item.hasOwnProperty('key')) {
        console.log ('Loop through results.')
      }
    })
```

This `forEach` function now loops through each value, but I don't know how to get the data in my database.

Comment: kind of a broad issue but to save something to your db I would assume you have some api in ruby to handle taking these values in? If so you just need a factory and do a $http.post('mySaveApi', { prop: value});

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used this,

```
angular.forEach(response.results, function(item){
  $scope.youtubeTrailer = [];
  $scope.youtubeTrailer.push(item.key);
  // console.log ($scope.youtubeTrailer)
  var youtubeLink = $scope.youtubeTrailer.toString();
  createTrailer.create({
    link:     youtubeLink,
    movie_id: $scope.movieListID.id
  })
})
```

I've created a forEach that inserts a `item.key` into the youtubeTrailer scope, then there's a create function, and then it does the loop again. Starting with clearing the youtubeTrailer scope.